# How to pass parameters through a delegate function

Tags: c#, function, methods, delegates

I'm trying to learn how to use a delegate function and I seem to have a problem when passing parameters through. Could someone suggest a simple way of doing this? I've read through a few tutorials on here but they get into complexities with LINQ that I'd rather try to avoid.

```
public delegate void DelegateFunction(int levelType, string levelName);
public DelegateFunction delegateFunction;
public  void LoadMap(int levelType, string levelName)
{
    gameManager.levelType = levelType;
    gameManager.started = false;
    Application.LoadLevel(levelName);
}
void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
{
    if(collision.gameObject.tag == "ZoneTransport")
    {
          delegateFunction+= LoadMap(0, "MainMap");//incorrect and will not compile
    }
}
```

Comment: There is some predefined delegates in .net. They are called `Action` and `Func` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.action(v=vs.110).aspx. Your delegateFunction can be writen as `public Action<int, string> delegateFunction`, which will use Action defined as `public delegate void Action<T1, T2>(T1 t1, T2 t2);`. Situations when you need to define your own deleage are rare.

Answer (score 0):

You can use such code:

```
if(collision.gameObject.tag == "ZoneTransport")
{
    delegateFunction = LoadMap;
    delegateFunction(0, "MainMap");
}
```

Although if that's what you are using delegates for then it is better to call function directly.

Comment: Thanks. I'm using this in Unity and there are certain events that I need to happen first before the scene is changed. Likewise I've just heard learned of delegates and eager to play around with them but was kind of stuck when passing parameters.

Comment: So if you want to fire an event you should be using event instead of delegate. You can read about [events in MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/awbftdfh.aspx)